# How to properly dockerize Ember.js FastBoot

Tags: docker, ember.js, ember.js-fastboot

Deploying a dockerized [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com) app stack can be done with three or four containers. For https it's easiest to proxy over a specialized container that handles vhosts and ssl certificates.

```
              Internet
                 │
               Server
                 │
             Container
            nginx-proxy
               https
                 │
         ╭───────┴───────╮
    Container        Container
      Ember             API
www.example.com   api.example.com
                         │
                     Container
                         DB
```

This works fine. But when the Ember app becomes a [FastBoot](https://ember-fastboot.com) app, the FastBoot server will do the requests to the API for the first pageview server-side. And the API is not reachable via DNS, nor is it https.

How should a setup like this realistically be accomplished?

Comment: I dont see why the ember container can not send a API request back to the nginx proxy?